# How to add a profile to JHipster

Tags: spring, jdbc, hive, jhipster, profile

So JHipster comes by default with the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles. I need to add another profile called 'hive' because I want to try and connect that profile to a HIVE database .. through an URL Connection String like this one:

```
"jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default"
```

I am a begginer with JHipster so I really don't know where to find the documentation if there is any. And so far I haven't seen any post about creating a new profile. I don't know what files to add, what things to change in order to use that profile rather than the 'dev' or 'prod' one, etc. I can see I have to create a new file called src/main/resources/config/application-hive.yml and that a lot of the code will go there ... but still I don't where is all the information about how to set all of those properties.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well ... I think it is ... because for example the JHipster 'dev' profile uses `io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect` as a jpa.database.platform property ... and I don't know which one corresponds for HIVE ... and I neither know where to find all the properties for jpa with HIVE :(

Answer (score 0):

JHipster can't support Hive because Liquibase does not support it and I don't think JPA/Hibernate supports it either.